# Cannot start server Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Get the following error

```
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
 Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
 Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
 from /Users/mehtaameet/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in      `require'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6
```

Comment: Which Operating System are you Using?

Comment: Looks like Mac OS, judging from the bit in the trace above saying that libmysqlclient.18.dylib cannot be loaded.

Comment: The OS would be Mac OS. "/Library" is a standard base dir on Mac OS, where it would be lowercase on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clue in your stack trace:

```
Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
```

You need to make sure that this sqlclient library is [on your load path](http://lightyearsoftware.com/2011/02/mysql-5-5-on-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 0):

I just did a bundle install and it worked! –